# How to find the smallest topologies containing the given sets.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\tau_1, \tau_2$ are the smallest topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ containing  the sets $S_1, S_2$, where $$S_1=\bigg\{\bigg(a, a+\frac{\pi}{n}\bigg):a\in\mathbb{Q},n\in\mathbb{N}\bigg\}, \ \ S_2=\big\{(a, b):a<b, a, b\in\mathbb{Q}\big\}, $$ Then show that $$\tau_1=\tau_2$$

To show that both the topologies are equal, we need to show that $$\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2\ \ \text{and}\ \  \tau_2\subseteq \tau_1.$$ How to start this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ are bases for the standard topology $\tau_e$ on $\Bbb R$. This is not hard to show using that $\mathbb{Q}$ is (order) dense in the reals, so for any interval $(c,d)$ where $c < d$ and any $x$ in it, we can find rationals $a< b$ such that $c < a < x < b< d$, so $\mathcal{S}_2$ is a base, or we find a rational $a$ and $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $c < a < x < a+\frac{\pi}{n} < d$ (we can make the gap as small as we need taking $n$ large enough).

It's clear that $\mathcal{S}_i \subseteq \tau_e$ for $i=1,2$ and so $\tau_i \subseteq \tau_e$ and as the sets are bases for $\tau_e$, in fact $\tau_e \subseteq \tau_i$ as well for $i=1,2$. So $$\tau_1 = \tau_2= \tau_e$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote the collection of finite intersection of a collection $\mathcal{C}$ by $I(\mathcal{C})$, i.e.

$$ I(\mathcal{C})=\{ \cap_{i\in F} A_i: \; \vert F\vert<\infty, A_i\in \mathcal{C} \; \text{for all} \; i\in F \}. $$

It's clear that $I(S_j)\subseteq \tau_j$ for  $j\in\{ 1,2 \}$, so if you show that for all $A\in S_1$, you can write

$$ A=\cup_{\alpha} E_\alpha \quad \text{where} \quad E_\alpha\in I(S_2), $$

then it will follow that $S_1\subseteq \tau_2$, and hence $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$.

Likewise showing something similar for $S_2$ with respect to $I(S_1)$, will imply that $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$.

It is relatively simple showing that $\tau_2\supseteq S_1$ using this line of reasoning.

For the other direction, let $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and we can write therefore

$$ a=\frac{m_1}{n}, b=\frac{m_2}{n} \quad \text{where} \quad m_1,m_2,n\in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Since $m_2-m_1>0$, there exists $n'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \frac{1}{2}\frac{m_2-m_1}{n}>\frac{\pi}{n'} $. Now define a collection
$$\mathcal{S}=\Big\{ (a', a'+\frac{\pi}{k}): \frac{m_1}{n}+\frac{\pi}{n'}\leq a'< b, a'+\frac{\pi}{k}< b  \Big\}.$$

Then $\mathcal{S}\subseteq S_1$, and

$$ (a,b)=(a,a+\frac{\pi}{n'})\cup \bigcup_{E\in\mathcal{S}} E \in \tau_1, $$

i.e. $S_2\subseteq \tau_1$.

There is probably a simpler way to write this argument which does not spring to mind at the moment.